# Given a bipartite graph $G=(U,V,E)$, what is the bound on $|V|$ given some conditions?

Tags: inequality, graph-theory, asymptotics, bipartite-graphs

I have a bipartite graph $G=(U,V,E)$ with the following two conditions:

- Every node $u\in U$ has a degree of at most a constant $c$, i.e., $1\leq \text{deg}(u)\leq c$;
- Every node $v\in V$ has a degree of at most $d$;
- No two nodes in $U$ are connected to the same set of nodes in $V$, i.e., for any two distinct $u_1,u_2\in U$, $\text{neighbor}(u_1)\neq\text{neighbor}(u_2)$.

Is it possible to show that the $|V|=\Theta(|U|)$? Note that here $|U|,d\rightarrow\infty$, $d=o(|U|)$, and every $u$ is connected to at least one $v\in V$. Otherwise, is there a way to derive the minimum size of $|V|$ in terms of $|U|$ and $d$?

For the case of $c=1$, it is clear that we have $|V|=|U|$, but things are not so clear to me when $c>1$. The best I could do for a general $c=\Theta(1)$ is $|V|=O(|U|/d)$: the $u$'s contribute at least 1 edge each giving us $|E|\geq|U|$. Dividing $|E|$ by $d$ gives us the bound.

Comment: What is $\omega(1)$?

Comment: I meant to say $d$ is increasing. Edited the question for clarity.

Comment: Interesting question, but it needs **much** cleaning up. You have 3 "variables" ($|U|, c, d$),and while each of them may tend to infinity (or not), there relative behavior is totally unspecificed. For example, if you have a sequence where $|U_n|=n, d_n=n^2$, your $|V| =O(|U|/d)$ formula says that $|V_n|$ should tend to $0$, which makes no sense.

Comment: Noted, thanks. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, there is to every node $u \in U$ a set of nodes $S_u \subseteq V$. Your first condition implies that the cardinality of each $S_u$ is somewhere in between $1$ and $c$. A priori, this means that there are
$$
\binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{2} + \cdots + \binom{n}{c}
$$
possible sets $S_u$, where $n = |V|$. When $d \to \infty$, this number can also be attained. From this we infer $|V| = \Omega(|U|^{1/c})$, and this is the best one can do.

Comment: "When $d \to \infty$, this number can also be attained." That is only true if $d$ can be chosen "big enough" for each $|U|$. But the condition requires $d=o(|U|)$, most importantly it can't be chosen "big enough" for each $|U|$ separately. In the ideal case for your example, when $|U|={n \choose 1}+\ldots+{n \choose c}$, each node $v \in V$ has degree ${n \choose 0}+\ldots+{n \choose (c-1)} \in \Theta(n^{c-1})$, so if $d$ is $o(|U|^{(c-1)/c}$), your construction will **not** be attainable. In other words, the condition on degree of nodes in $V$ does not simply go away.

Comment: The condition was added only after I posted my answer.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.